# To write a regular expression for the find_all_phone function

Tags: python-3.x, regex

Now in the text we will search for the telephone number of Ukraine in the international format, the template of which is as follows: +380(67)777-7-777 or +380(67)777-77-77

Write a regular expression for the find_all_phones function, which will find all phone numbers according to the specified pattern in the text (parameter text) and return a list of matches obtained from the text.

For the sake of simplification, let's assume that:

we use only numbers and symbols +, (, ) and -
the phone number starts with the + symbol
phone pattern symbol + then three digits 380, symbol (, two digits, symbol ), three digits, symbol -, one or two digits, symbol -, two or three digits
The length of the phone number template is always 17 characters
This regular expression by no means claims to cover all possible variants of phone numbers.

```
import re


def find_all_phones(text):
    result = re.findall(r"(\+380\(\d{2}\)\d{3}-\d{1,2})", text)
    return result
```

The find_all_phones function returns an incorrect result: ['+380(67)777-7-77', '+380(67)777-77-77', '+380(67)777-77-78']. It was expected that the find_all_phones function when receiving the parameter 'Irma +380(67)777-7-771 second +380(67)777-77-77 aloha a@test.com abc111@test.com.net +380(67)111 -777-777+380(67)777-77-787' will return the following list ['+380(67)777-7-771', '+380(67)777-77-77', '+380(67 )777-77-78']

Comment: What's the question? This seems like a project/assignment you were given. `The task will be similar to the previous one`, if the task is a different question please link to that if it is needed.

Comment: task from the courses yes with which there were difficulties

Comment: Unfortunately, no, this link does not fit, there more complex options.